# RadioGroup Inside Dialog Alert Crashes The App When .positive

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog that has a Radiogroup of 5 buttons. When OK is pressed, the app crashes whether I chose a radio button or not. Itried different methods for Radiogroup but all fail. If someone can help me, I would be thankful.

PS. I have a switch case that is calling this Alert Dialog Activity. colorpickdialog();

This is my Alert Dialog XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radiosizeg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bgadddialogsize"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
<RadioButton
    android:text="@string/sizesmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sizesmall"/>

<RadioButton
    android:text="@string/sizemed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sizemed" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="@string/sizelar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sizelar" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="@string/sizefill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sizefill" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="@string/sizecustom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sizecustom" />
</RadioGroup>
```

and this is my MainActivity.class:

```
public void colorpickdialog() {
    // get prompts.xml view
    final RadioGroup radiosizeg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiosizeg);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView2 = layoutInflater2.inflate(R.layout.colorpickdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder2.setView(promptView2);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder2.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    radiosizeg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                            int id = radiosizeg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            switch (id) {
                                case R.id.sizesmall:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.sizemed:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.sizelar:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"C", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.sizefill:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.sizecustom:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"E", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    onCheckedChanged(radioGroup, i);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
```

The error stacktrace

```
10-27 20:56:53.753 4312-4327/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build
10-27 20:56:53.959 4312-7462/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
10-27 20:56:54.025 13521-13539/? E/HwLauncher: SettingsEx , no such field.
10-27 20:56:54.088 8152-8242/? E/PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@4d74931, packageNames: null
```

Comment: Please submit the error log

Comment: That isn't an error log. Notice there is no `? E/`. You only have Info and Warning messages there.

Comment: This logs are of all the app collectively. filter the logs and submit again. If using android studio. you can see filter option on right side of android monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the sulotion.

The problem is that the radiogroup is defined in the actual view:

```
final RadioGroup radiosizeg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiosizeg);
```

However, I have inflated the view as:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView2 = layoutInflater2.inflate(R.layout.colorpickdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder2.setView(promptView2);
```

So, the solution is to define the view inside promptView2:

```
final RadioGroup radiosizeg = (RadioGroup) promptView2.findViewById(R.id.radiosizeg)
```

Great();

Answer (score 1):

Well I got an easy way to handle Radiogroup in AlertDialog box:
The issue was on each time a dialog is created child gets the additional id:

Xml Code: Just Radio group part:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_Payment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_25sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/Paid"
                android:textColor="@color/green"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/Trail"
                android:textColor="@color/orange"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/blocked"
                android:textColor="@color/colorRed"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

And the code :

```
    public void updateStatus() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_popup, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    RelativeLayout rrSubmit = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rr_submit);
    RelativeLayout rr_lg_cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rr_lg_cancel);
    RadioGroup rg_Payment = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rg_Payment);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    paymentType = "";
    rg_Payment.setOnCheckedChangeListener((radioGroup, id) -> {
        int position = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() % radioGroup.getChildCount();
        setLog("MyRadioChoice", "Choice" + position);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                paymentType = "Blocked";
                break;
            case 1:
                paymentType = "Paid";
                break;
            case 2:
                paymentType = "Trail";
                break;
            default:
                paymentType = "";
        }
    });

    rrSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    //do something        
    });


    rr_lg_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

Here below method is used to solve the issue of dynamical creation of radio button

```
   int position = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()% radioGroup.getChildCount();
```